# Developer minijobs portal?

Tags: jobs

I don't know if that exists, but I am looking for a minijob portal for developers. 
I would like to offer mini developer tasks for money.

Does this exist ?

regards

Comment: Yes but for really minijobs. For example an codeexample for drawing a rectangle on an android device for 50 $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one i know is freelancer.com I'm sure that many people over there would be interested in quick projects.

Or another way would be to approach developer one on one and propose those minijobs, you could pay them thru paypal for instance